# Yii Framework, CException Property "User.login_attempts" is not defined

Tags: php, yii

I am developing a blog system in YII Framework by referring [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/prototype.auth) tutorial. However I am facing an authentication error in my LoginForm.

```
CException

Property "User.login_attempts" is not defined.

/home/btspdcux1/project/common/lib/Yii/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(144)
```

I am implementing same exactly as given in yii framework tutorial and did all steps according to that but still facing the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this while searching for your error

[yiiframework site](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36774-database-connection/page__view__findpost__p__177491)

In short though.

Declare the property 'login_attempts' in the class User.
It should be,

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
   public $login_attempts;
   .....
   .....
}
```

Comment: jka, can you advise what your solution was?